# Combining Dynamic Tables Into One Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-optimization

Is there a clean way to combine the SQL below into 1 statement?  The FilterID's can be zero-length, so the `Filters` table is optional.  So, unless there is a better way to do it, I am "forced" to use the EXISTS logic below.

**I Already Realize...**
I already realize I can build a dynamic String and use the `EXEC` to run it...but that is slow.

The **Document-to-DocumentMetadata relationship is:** 1 `Document` to many `DocumentMetadata`'s
The **Filter-to-DocumentMetadata relationship is:**  1 `Filter` to many `DocumentMetadata`'s

**The SQL Is As Follows:**

```
   DECLARE @SearchTerms NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @FilterIDs  VARCHAR(100)
    SET @SearchTerms        = '7%'
    SET @FilterIDs      = '12'
    ------------------------
    DECLARE @Filters TABLE (FilterID int)

    IF(@FilterIDs IS NOT NULL)
            INSERT INTO @Filters SELECT items AS INT FROM Split(@filterIDs, ',')

    IF EXISTS(SELECT FilterID FROM @Filters)
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                Document.ID AS DocumentID
                ,Document.SourceID
                ,Document.Name
                ,Document.Title
                ,Document.DocumentUrl
                ,Document.DocType
                ,Document.DocumentModifiedDate
                ,Document.Library
                ,DocumentMetadata.ID AS DocumentMetadataID
                ,DocumentMetadata.DocumentID
                ,DocumentMetadata.FilterID
                ,DocumentMetadata.Value
            FROM Document
            JOIN DocumentMetadata
                ON DocumentMetadata.DocumentID = Document.ID
            JOIN Filter
                ON Filter.ID = DocumentMetadata.FilterID
                AND Filter.ID IN (SELECT FilterID FROM @Filters)
            WHERE
                Document.Name LIKE @SearchTerms
                OR Document.Title LIKE @SearchTerms
            ORDER BY
                Document.Name, Document.Title
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                Document.ID AS DocumentID
                ,Document.SourceID
                ,Document.Name
                ,Document.Title
                ,Document.DocumentUrl
                ,Document.DocType
                ,Document.DocumentModifiedDate
                ,Document.Library
                ,DocumentMetadata.ID AS DocumentMetadataID
                ,DocumentMetadata.DocumentID
                ,DocumentMetadata.FilterID
                ,DocumentMetadata.Value
            FROM Document
            JOIN DocumentMetadata
                ON DocumentMetadata.DocumentID = Document.ID
            JOIN Filter
                ON Filter.ID = DocumentMetadata.FilterID
            WHERE
                Document.Name LIKE @SearchTerms
                OR Document.Title LIKE @SearchTerms
            ORDER BY
                Document.Name, Document.Title
        END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JOIN Filter ON Filter.ID = DocumentMetadata.FilterID 
AND (Filter.ID IN (SELECT FilterID FROM @Filters) OR @FilterIDs is null)
```

That should cover whether you have items in the @filters table or you had null come in for the filtersID (which drives the Filters table). In the case null came in the OR clause lets the record thru, so it relies on the other part of the join clause which is common between your statements. That should let you just use 1 select clause to cover both.

Comment: Note that this method can be a performance killer on large data sets; on smaller tables, it's fine (anc certainly easier to maintain).

Comment: @Stuart Do you have another way?

Comment: If the number of items within @Filters is quite high, then it could suffer, but on low numbers, it will be fine.

Comment: @Andrew Out of curiosity, how high is "quite high"...5, 30, 100?

Comment: I remember on SQL Server 2005 RTM the query plan behaviour changed at 64 items, later on that changed - the best approach is to run some tests with your data. I would also point out that the goal was to solve the double statements - using IN on a large number of values is a different question, and I am pretty sure it has come up on SO a number of times before

Comment: @Andrew already answered it.  This is one of those cases where the best performing solution is the most difficult to maintain (which is the version in your original question).  As to where the breaking point will be, that's difficult to say: it depends on your hardware.  What you will notice is that you will see a TABLE or INDEX SCAN.